# Need help styling icons

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to style icons, i am having a little trouble as the styling of the icon is pushing the border-top and border-bottom attributes out of place. As you can see below. any help will be appreciated, its probable something i overlooked in css i am not to sure.

[image]

I am trying to achieve the following:
[image]

my code is:

```css
h3{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font:'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    color: #6b6b6b;
    margin-left: 30%;
        overflow: hidden;

}

/*order icon*/
a#order{
    background: url("./Images/bell1.png") no-repeat !important;
    display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 20%;
    background-position: 0 0;
```

```html
 <a  id="order" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Order');"><h3 id="order">Orders</h3></a>
            <div id="Order" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: You have the same ID defined for your `anchor` and `h3` tags. IDs are unique.

Comment: one isn't in use, was put there for trial and error purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. it's a little unconventional but it works really well for navigation items. I have re-organized your html and css a bit for readability and modern web. that translateY won't work on less than IE9 so if you're going that route, stick with the vertical align.

http://jsfiddle.net/calebswank/qm4yqL8b/

```
<a id="order" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Order');">
 <h3>Orders</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it now works once i done made some adjustments